# Node.js base64 decode with utf8 and gunzip

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I have a base64 string, which I need to decode with utf8, which is then gzipped, so then I need to gunzip this.

What I'm doing is:

```
var data = 'base64/gzipped data'
var buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
zlib.gunzip(buffer, function (err, dezipped) { 
  dezipped.toString();
});
```

This is all fine, however it's not getting the utf8 characters.  I could do `.toString('utf8')` on the base64 buffer, but it doesn't seem gunzip will accept a string.

Anyone have any suggestions on a good way to do this?

EDIT:

This is essentially what I'm trying to do in nodejs, which works in php
`gzinflate(substr(base64_decode($base64),10));`